# Invalid value for 'src' in react js

Tags: reactjs, chakra-ui

I imported `Image` from **charka UI** and I put the following `src={imageSrc}`

`imageSrc` is  an object attribute in this case.

`imageSrc: getImageSrc: () =\> require("../images/photo3.jpg")`

and I get an error that says invalid value for `src` in the console.

I tried to directly put the value itself instead of a function `src ="../images/photo3.jpg"` and it didn't work